# MySQL storing double space " " as question mark "?"

Tags: php, mysql

For some reason MySQL is storing double spaces as question marks in the database. I feel like this is probably an issue involving the character set, but I am unsure. Any thoughts? Thanks.

Comment: Can you show us what query have this beauvoir?

Comment: It is an issue with your chatacter set. The one doing the saving and the database do not match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which unicode space character are you talking about?  See http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/chars/spaces.html

Specifically:

- what character do you intend to upload
- what character is in your program befoer it uploads
- what character is in the database
- what character is displayed on your terminal when you look in the database?

Answer (score 0):

This problem can solve by replace double space by single space like :
$new_array_products=str_replace('  ',' ',$new_array_products);

Comment: How would that store double spaces?